# Canvas collision detection wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, collision-detection

Trying to position randomly figures with collision detection, but having exception with invalid cast. Even don't know how to solve with other variants..

Here drawing figure where "Surface" is Canvas from xaml

```
var elipse = new Ellipse
   {
       Width = 100,
       Height = 50,
       Stroke = Brushes.RoyalBlue,
       StrokeThickness = 1.5
   };
   Surface.Children.Add(elipse);
   collision = CollisionDetection(Surface.Children, elipse);
   if (collision)
   {
       Canvas.SetLeft(elipse, e.GetPosition(this).X);
       Canvas.SetTop(elipse, e.GetPosition(this).Y);
   }
```

and bool method where i'm getting detection

```
private static bool CollisionDetection(UIElementCollection children, Shape shape)
    {
        return children.Cast<Rect>().All(child => !shape.RenderedGeometry.Bounds.IntersectsWith(child));
    }
```

In this method getting invalid cast detection

**UPDATE 2**
Have tried this variant, but it always return true.

```
list.Add(elipse);
collision = CollisionDetection(list, elipse);

private static bool CollisionDetection(IEnumerable<Shape> children, Shape shape)
    {
        return children.All(child => !child.RenderedGeometry.Bounds.IntersectsWith(shape.RenderedGeometry.Bounds));
    }
```

Comment: You are casting Ellipse to Rect. Isn't that the problem?

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan I think it is.. how to cast Ellipse, Rectangle and Polygon into one variable? I've trying as Shape, but having invalid cast error.

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan check please upd2